# Crashlytics Android app, is it possible to show update version of app dialog inside app?

Tags: android, updates, crashlytics, beta, crashlytics-beta

I am using Fabric and Beta from Crashlytics for a while now, and it works perfect.
The iOS version of the app has an dialog, that pops up when you start the app, if there's another, newer version of the app in Beta, than the one you have installed.
I need to implement this in Android, but I cannot find any documentation about how this could be possible. Did anyone manage to implement this on Android?

Comment: Do you want to implement it for your own app?

Comment: Yes. So I have Beta implemented, and I have a buildmachine, that builds my app each day at a given hour, and loads the apk to BETA by Crashlytics. Now, after a new build is built, I get a notification from the Beta app. But if I enter the android app, it does nothing.
On iOS if I get that notification, If I enter my app (not the BETA app), I will get a popup that says that theres a new version up on Crashlytics, and press here to install. How can I implement that popup in my app?